# proper use of stream in a computationally intensive program

Tags: c++, fstream

I have a program that may take up to 3-4 hours to finish. Underway I need to output various information into a general file "info.txt". Here is how I do it currently

```
char dateStr [9];
char timeStr [9];
_strdate(dateStr);
_strtime(timeStr);

ofstream infoFile("info.txt", ios::out);
infoFile << "foo @ " << timeStr << " , " << dateStr << endl;
infoFile.close();
```

This I do five times during a single run. My question is the following: Is it most proper (efficiency-wise and standard-wise) to

1. close infoFile after each output (and, consequently, use five ofstreams infoFile1, infoFile2, ..., infoFile5, one for each time I output)
2. or only to use "infoFile" and, consequently, have it open during the entire run?

EDIT: By "a single run" I mean a single run of the program. So by "five times during a single run" I mean that I output something to info.txt when running the program once (which takes 3-4 hours).

Comment: that depends on what you're trying to achieve... Since your program runs for so much time and you only write to the file 5 times I would say that your current approach is better. Creating the stream and opening the file is negligible next to the runtime of the application.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "five times during a single run"? Do you mean that in the whole of the 3-4 hours you will only output to a file 5 times?

Comment: @JonBentley yes, that is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @niles_1710373 in that case, stop worrying about the efficiency of this operation. If I were you, I'd just keep the file open. Another option would be to open the file for each write, but use `ios::app` *after* the first write.

Comment: @MichaelWild I wondered about that myself.  Does he want a file with five lines in it after he's finished, or is some other process or person reading the file while his program is running, and the file should only contain the last state?

Comment: @JamesKanze What I want is a single file with 5 lines in it, so I will have to append. But my question is valid, regardless if I append or output to a new file.

Comment: @niles_1710373 If you want five lines, keeping the file open is the simplest solution.  If you want to close it, you would have to add the `ios::app` flag to every open but the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're trying to do.  If the code you
post does what you want, it's certainly the best solution.  If
you want the values *appended*, then you might want to keep the
file open.

Some other considerations:

- unless you close the file or flush the data, external
  programs may not see the data immediately.
- When you open the file, any existing file with that name will be
  truncated: an external program which tries to read the file at
  precisely this moment won't see anything.
- Flushing after each output (automatic if you use `std::endl`),
  and seeking to the start before each output, will solve the
  previous problem (and if the data is as small as it seems, the
  write will be atomic), but could result in misleading data if
  the values written have different lengths---the file length will
  *not* be shortened.  (Probably not the
  case here, but something to be considered.)

With regards to performance: you're talking about an operation
which lasts at most a couple of milliseconds, and takes place
once or twice an hour.  Whether it takes one millisecond, or
ten, is totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

First; get numbers before optimizing, use a profiler. Then you know which parts take the most time. 
If you don't have a profiler, think a bit before doing anything. How many runs will you do during those 3-4 hours? If it's few things that only happen once per run are probably less likely to be good targets for optimization, if it's lots and lots of runs those parts can be considered as well since disc access can be rather slow.

With that said, I've saved a bit of time in previous projects by reusing streams instead of opening and closing.

Comment: Uh, the question says clearly that he's writing five (!) lines during a run of the program that takes multiple hours...

Comment: *"If you don't have a profiler, ..."* - then get one! [Sleepy](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy) is free, easy to use (almost zero learning curve), and does a good job of basic profiling.

Comment: I don't need a profiler to know that optimization here is irrelevant.

Comment: Hm, I seem to have misread things. I thought he was writing lots of stuff. Nevermind me then.

Answer (score 0):

This is a clear case of [Premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize)

It makes no actual difference to the performance of your application which approach you take as this is something that happens only 5 times during the scope of several hours.

Profile your application as the previous answer suggested and use that to identify the **REAL** bottlenecks in your code.

Only case I could think of where it would matter to you is if you wanted to prevent the `info.txt` from being deleted/edited during the scope of your application run-time. In which case you'd want to keep the stream alive. Otherwise it doesn't matter.

Comment: Keeping the file open doesn't prevent it from being deleted (unless, perhaps, your system is broken, as some widely used ones are).  The real issue, maybe, is what happens when you open a closed file.  The contents of the file disappear each time you open it, until it is rewritten.

Comment: It actually is very platform specific but the comment is right in pointing it out. However, on most OS's you can lock files for exclusive read/write access and hence I just wanted to give an example that merits the "keeping the stream open" approach.